Return paginated list of rows from table where only the latest row is returned filtered by one column and deduplicated on another
Imagine a table of user messages that looks like this:
| ID | MESSAGE | RECIPIENT_ID | ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID | SENT_AT             |
| 1  | Blah.   | 10           | 1                  | 2024-09-10T10:10:00 |
| 2  | Blah2   | 10           | 2                  | 2024-09-11T12:20:00 |
| 3  | Blah3   | 10           | 1                  | 2024-09-12T15:10:00 |
| 4  | Blah4   | 10           | 1                  | 2024-09-13T16:10:00 |

What I would like to send back is the latest message to a user, with the ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID deduplicated. i.e. Each row will have a unique ultimate parent id. I will be sending a pagination object (Pageable) which will hopefully take care of the pagination for me.
Basically the query on the above table should send back:
| ID | MESSAGE | RECIPIENT_ID | ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID | SENT_AT             |
| 2  | Blah2   | 10           | 2                  | 2024-09-11T12:20:00 |
| 4  | Blah4   | 10           | 1                  | 2024-09-13T16:10:00 |

I am using Spring and Spring Data JPA. But if it has to be done using native SQL that is fine. What I have tried, but doesn't work is:
@Query(value = "SELECT dm FROM " +
        "(SELECT DISTINCT d.ultimateParentId from DirectMessage d WHERE dm.recipient.id = :recipientId) DirectMessage dm " +
        "ORDER BY dm.sentAt DESC", nativeQuery = true)
Page<DirectMessage> findPaginatedDirectMessagesByRecipientIdGroupByUltimateParentId(Long recipientId, Pageable pg);

Any help on this is greatly appreciated because I can't find a solution, either in my own head or online!
EDIT: I am now trying:
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ultimate_parent_id) * FROM direct_message WHERE recipient_id = :recipientId ORDER BY ultimate_parent_id DESC) direct_message ORDER BY sent_at DESC", nativeQuery = true)

Which is giving me the error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

****************************** EDIT 2: ******************************
Inspired by this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/612268/1879196
This is eventually what I got working:
@Query(value = "SELECT outerDM.* FROM direct_message outerDM " +
        "INNER JOIN (SELECT ultimate_parent_id, MAX(sent_at) AS last_sent FROM direct_message " +
        "WHERE recipient_id = :recipientId GROUP BY ultimate_parent_id) innerDM " +
        "ON outerDM.ultimate_parent_id = innerDM.ultimate_parent_id AND outerDM.sent_at = innerDM.last_sent", nativeQuery = true)
Page<DirectMessage> findPaginatedDirectMessagesByRecipientIdGroupByUltimateParentId(Long recipientId, Pageable pg);

I hope this saves saves someone some time in the future who may be stuck pulling their hair out like I was!

Does the RECIPIENT_ID matter? If it does, add at least one different RECIPIENT_ID value to the sample data.

I suggest the following query:
select U.*
  from USER_MESSAGES U
  join (
        select ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID
              ,max(SENT_AT) as SENT_TS
          from USER_MESSAGES
         group by ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID
       ) V
    on U.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID = V.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID
   and U.SENT_AT = V.SENT_TS

Refer to this db<>fiddle
Here is the query result for the sample data in your question:



ID
MESSAGE
RECIPIENT_ID
ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID
SENT_AT




2
Blah2
10
2
2024-09-11 12:20:00


4
Blah4
10
1
2024-09-13 16:10:00




If the combination of ultimate_parent_id and sent_at isn't guaranteed to be unique, then this query could return duplicate rows.

@JohnH correct :-) However it appears (at least to me) that two messages can't have the same SENT_AT.

Ok, thank you, and how would you add a recipientId = :recipientId to this query - to send back this for a particular recipient?

So I tried:
@Query(value = "select U.* from direct_message U join (select ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID, max(SENT_AT) as SENT_TS from direct_message group by ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID) V on U.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID = V.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID and U.SENT_AT = V.SENT_TS WHERE recipient_id = :recipientId", nativeQuery = true)
But I am getting:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

@lenny I don't see DISTINCT or ORDER BY in the [SQL] query in my answer. Adding a where RECIPIENT_ID = 10 does not give any error. Refer to this db<>fiddle

Okay, thank you, I just updated my original post with what I got working in the end. Let me know if you think I should accept this answer as it may also solve the problem in another way.

The following query will return the most recent message for each ultimate_parent_id:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ultimate_parent_id) id, message, recipient_id, ultimate_parent_id, sent_at
  FROM t
  ORDER BY ultimate_parent_id, sent_at DESC, id DESC;

I've assumed that id is unique and have included it in the ORDER BY to ensure that the returned rows are deterministic even if the combination of ultimate_parent_id and sent_at aren't unique.

Ok, thank you, and how would you add a recipientId = :recipientId to this query - to send back this for a particular recipient?

Just add a WHERE clause with the selection criteria; e.g., WHERE recipient_id = $1. Pass the value as a parameter from the calling code.

I added one row with a different Recipient_id value to the example. The content of this row does not matter, because it is eliminated at the first selection.
Order by SENT_AT desc,id - there id is for reliability, for case when sent_at when values match (if this is possible).
@Recipient_Id is a parameter for query or variable, declared in script.
See example



ID
MESSAGE
RECIPIENT_ID
ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID
SENT_AT




1
Blah.
10
1
2024-09-10 10:10:00.000


2
Blah2
10
2
2024-09-11 12:20:00.000


3
Blah3
10
1
2024-09-12 15:10:00.000


4
Blah4
10
1
2024-09-13 16:10:00.000


5
Blah4
11
1
2024-09-13 16:11:00.000



declare @Recipient_Id int=10;

select *
from(
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by Recipient_id,ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID order by SENT_AT 
desc,id) rn
  from DirectMessage dm
  where recipient_id=@Recipient_Id  -- this is query parameter
)t
where rn=1




ID
MESSAGE
RECIPIENT_ID
ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID
SENT_AT
rn




2
Blah2
10
2
2024-09-11 12:20:00.000
1


4
Blah4
10
1
2024-09-13 16:10:00.000
1



fiddle
